Matthew 21:43 - To whom does Jesus refer when He says, "it will be given to a people (ἔθνει) producing its fruits"?
Matthew 21:43 (ESV):

Therefore I tell you, the kingdom of God will be taken away from you
and given to a people producing its fruits. (ESV)

What is the significance of 'bearing its fruit' and its consequences?

The context identifies who Jesus addressed in that stern admonition. It comes at the end of a series of parables Jesus spoke while in Jerusalem's temple courts, after he had been challenged by the chief priests and elders as to what authority he had to teach there (21:23). Those parables were addressed to those who challenged him, and those who heard him gladly. But the admonition in verse 43 was aimed purely at those who challenged his authority:

"And when the chief priests and Pharisees had heard his parables, they
perceived that he spake of them." Matthew 21:45 A.V.

This identifies one group - those from whom the kingdom of God would be taken; religious Jews who did not believe Jesus to be the foretold Messiah. Jesus underscored that by saying all who stumbled over himself (the stone of stumbling - Isaiah 8:13-15 as confirmed in 1 Peter 2:6-8) would be ground to powder by it, as if under a millstone.
Identifying the other group - "a nation bringing forth the fruits" of God's kingdom.  It is the word ethnos used in the A.V., which means a 'nation'. The word for 'people' is laos. The verse in question has ethnos.
Shortly before Jesus said those things, he had caused an unproductive fig tree to wither simply by a verbal curse. This gives the clue. No fruit was on that tree, nor would it ever produce fruit, once cursed. This can be taken as a symbol for what would happen after the nation that had been blessed with the presence of the foretold Messiah still did not produce spiritual fruit, as was expected from a nation bearing God's name, who were to be his witnesses amongst all the other nations (Isaiah 43:10). That privilege would be taken from them and bestowed upon other people, from other nations, who would produce the spiritual fruit the Lord looks for in those who claim to belong to him.
Of course, many Jewish people did believe in Jesus, and did produce that spiritual fruit (as also through the centuries to this very day). All the initial members of the 'nation' of spiritual Israel were Jewish men and women. But shortly after the Jewish nation, as a nation, had rejected the authority of Christ, the Gentiles were enabled to come flooding in, to join their Jewish brothers and sisters as the spiritual Israel of God. Being a natural-born, fleshly Jew was no longer what counted, as explained by the apostle Paul, himself a learned Jewish teacher: "For neither they themselves who are circumcised keep the law... For in Christ Jesus neither circumcision availeth any thing, nor uncircumcision, but a new creature. And as many as walk according to this rule, peace be on them, and mercy, and upon the Israel of God." Galatians 6:13-16 A.V.
This other group, then, are all who bear the fruit of the Spirit, that Spirit of Christ indwelling believers who makes them new creatures in Christ. The fruit they bear brings glory to Christ, as Paul said just a few verses earlier:

"There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither male nor female; for
ye are all one in Christ Jesus. And if ye be Christ's, then are ye
Abraham's seed, and heirs according to the promise...
But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, longsuffering,
gentleness, goodness, faith, meekness, temperance: against such there
is no law. And they that are Christ's have crucified the flesh with
the affections and lusts. If we live in the Spirit, let us also walk
in the Spirit." Galatians 3:28-29 & 5:22-25 A.V.


The primary meaning of ἔθνος in the New Testament is Gentiles/nations.  When it means people, it means people group (ethnic) rather than people in general.  Of course, there is a qualification, "producing its fruits."  Thus, it wasn't taken away from the Jews who produced fruits, and only given to the Gentiles who produced fruits.  One can see this as pointing to Christians who produce fruits.
Figure 1. Senses of ἔθνος in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software).

In the Septuagint (LXX) ἔθνος primarily translates the Hebrew word for Gentile/nation (גּוֹי).
Figure 2. Hebrew words ἔθνος translates in the Old Testament (generated by Logos Bible Software).


TO WHOM DOES IT REFER?Although ethnos (Gk.) usually refers to a "nation", it can  by inference also mean a "people group." (a sub-group united by some characteristic).
We are given a hint by Jesus, in the scriptures, saying that tax-collectors and prostitutes would sit down and feast with Abraham, before He would allow any self-righteous, unbelieving, antagonistic religious people come in to enjoy it!
Acceptance of Jesus as the fulfilment of the prophecies, a change of character, a life of faith, and essentially, a manifestation of the "fruit of the Spirit", are what God was desiring in the "people group" He wanted to exist in His Kingdom of light.
These were lacking in many, if not most, of the religious leaders who chose to oppose Christ and His message of selflessness and charity. Greedy, egotism, popularity, fame-seeking, preference, ostentiousness, favoritism, racism, were their daily characteristics of conduct.
Jesus was not being anti-Semitic, by any means. But He was inclusive to the max, favoring Jew and ethnics (foreigners) of all nationalities and races. But in all those races or social groups---whether Jew or Ethnics---what He did require was integrity, character, and above all, faith. This love-standard of God resulted in the acceptance of Joe Plumber, Tax-collector, Prostitute, Farmer John, Roman centurion, Leper, and even Fishermen!
